# Convert XHR response or Fetch or Async/Await responses to a JavaScript Object

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, xmlhttprequest, fetch-api

so I have an api, what I want to achieve is convert the response(array of objects) gotten from the api to a JavaScript object, currently I've tried a lot of methods ranging from xhrResponse, fetch, async/await, with all this method it returns the responses successfully, what I then want to achieve is taking those responses and converting it to a JavaScript object, here's my code snippet:-

const url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1";

xhr response------->

```js
// Using xhr method
const XMLHttpRequest = require('xhr2');
const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', url);
xhr.responseType = 'json';
xhr.onload = function() {
  const responseObj = xhr.response;
  console.log(responseObj)
};
xhr.send();
```

What I tried doing her, since the response is gotten from the onload function, I tried to directly initialize an object from the response using const getObj = xhr.onload, but I discovered it runs only within the onload function and not outside..

Then I tried using fetch----------->

```js
fetch(url)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => {data.forEach(selectedItem => {
        const nameMarker = selectedItem.date;
        console.log(nameMarker);
    });
  });
```

what I tried doing was assigning the parsed value in the next .then(), "var obj" returned undefined, here's the code snippet------------>

```js
var obj;

fetch(url)
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(data => {
    obj = data;
   })
  .then(() => {
    console.log(obj);
   });
```

What exactly can I do to convert the response I'm getting from the clg to a JavaScript object??

I'm running a cloud function on Firebase, I've setup my get request from a collection, the data gotten from the api is meant to perform a particular scheduled function, here's the code snippet------->

```js
const functions = require("firebase-functions/v1");
const {getFirestore} = require("firebase-admin/firestore");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
const serviceAccount = require("./service-account.json");

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
});

const moment = require("moment");
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");
const db = admin.firestore();

// main app
const app = express();
app.use(cors({origin: true}));

// Fetch - All Details from firestore from a Particular Collection
app.get("/api/getALl", (req, res) => {
  (async () => {
    try {
      const query = db.collection("alarm");
      const response = [];
      await query.get().then((data) => {
        const docs = data.docs;
        docs.map((doc) => {
          const selectedItem = {
            date: doc.data().date,
            userName: doc.data().userName,
          };
          response.push(selectedItem);
        });
        return response;
      });
      // return res.status(200).send({status:
      //   "Successful", data: response});
      return res.json(response);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      return res.status(500).send({status: "fatal error", msg: error});
    }
  })();
});

// Run a function every minute
exports.helloEveryMinute = functions.pubsub.schedule("*/1 * * * *").onRun(
    async () => {
    // I need to get the array of objects to run certain conditions
      const date = new Date();
      if (userFind!==null) {
        await getFirestore()
            .collection("notifications")
            .doc()
            .set({
              title: "Notify",
              timeStamp: date.toLocaleString(),
              msg: `${userFind.userName} stoorage has expired`,
            });
      } else {
        return null;
      }
    });
```

So basically I'm getting the response successfully but I need it as an object...

This is the part of the code I'm trying to convert to an object---->

```js
const url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1";

function getObj(url) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    const XMLHttpRequest = require('xhr2');
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onload = function() {
      resolve(this.responseText);
    };
    xhr.onerror = reject;
    xhr.open('GET', url);
    xhr.send();
  });
}

const result = getObj(url);
console.log(result)
```

It returns

```js
Promise { <pending> };
```

Comment: In your last example `obj` will contain the array of objects. The problem is simply because the code is asynchronous, and you're most likely trying to use it somewhere else in your codebase before the value has been set. To be honest, the question is a little all over the place with some clear confusion. It would be better if you could edit the question to give a description of what you're trying to do, and some additional code - ie. what you're trying to do with `obj` after it's retrieve from your request to the API

Comment: @Rory McCrossan Okay I'm running a cloud function on Firebase, I've setup my get request from a collection, the data gotten from the api is meant to perform a particular scheduled function, the code snippet is updated above

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I've updated the code snippets

Comment: Use `const data = await query.get();`, then `const response = data.docs.map((doc) => ({ date: doc.data().date, userName: doc.data().userName }));`.

Comment: Notice that your current code (with `const response = []; await query.get().then((data) => { … response.push(…); … })`) is cumbersome but should still work. What exactly is the problem you are experiencing with that?

Comment: @Bergi I'm getting the response fully from the api but I want to convert the response gotten from the api to a JavaScript object

Comment: Ah, I thought the issue was with your serverside code.

Comment: You *are* getting the response as a JS object already - `data` is that object that you're looking for. You just cannot get it immediately, or outside of the promise handler. You must wait for it, just like you did wait for the result of the `query.get()` method in your serverside code. There is no way around waiting. See the duplicate for various strategies.

Comment: Please show the part of the code that is trying to use `obj` and failing to get it as a javascript object.

Comment: @Bergi I've updated the code snippet now...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255973/discussion-between-deezy-and-bergi).

Comment: "*It returns `Promise { <pending> }`*" - yes, that is expected, as you did not wait for the promise result. Use either `const result = await getObj(url); console.log(result);` or `await getObj(url).then(result => { console.log(result); });`. There is no way around that. You must move all the code that needs to use `result`, and therefore needs to run asynchronously when the result arrives, inside the `then` callback or after the `await`.